# Exit promise chain on first error callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, jasmine

I have a chain of promises that looks like this:

```
   Transaction.findPublic({}).then(function(transactions) {
      combined = combined.concat(transactions);
      return JoinEvent.find().exec();
    }, function(err) {
      return res.status(503).send(err);
    }).then(function(joins) {
      combined = combined.concat(joins);
      return NewCategoryEvent.find().exec();
    }, function(err) {
      return res.status(503).send(err);
    });
```

It's really unclear if this `res.send()` will actually exit my promise chain. It might just get sent into the next `.then()`, which will definitely not work.

I'm trying to test this with the jasmine test framework, but I am using my own mocked res object. The mock obviously does not have logic to exit the function, but I'm wondering if the real express res object does.

Will `return res.send()` exit this promise chain? If not, can I instead break out by throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Transaction.findPublic({}).then(function(transactions) {
      combined = combined.concat(transactions);
      return JoinEvent.find().exec();
    }).then(function(joins) {
      combined = combined.concat(joins);
      return NewCategoryEvent.find().exec();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      res.status(503).send(err);
    });
```

**Explanation**: When you chain promises and a `reject`(error) occurs, it'll skip all following `fullfill`(success) callbacks till a `rejection`(error) callback is found, it calls the first found rejection callback( then continues on to the next promise), if none is found, it throws an error.

also `catch(func)` is equivalent to `then(undefined, func)` but more readable.

for more info : [promise error handling.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-error-handling)

Comment: Will the latter solution catch an error that happens in the middle of the chain, say in the second one I've provided or a hypothetical third? Also very clean and understandable answer.

Comment: @ritmatter yes, it catches, if nothing in front of it caught the reject already, also I have updated the answer, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, good solution to a topic thats surprisingly hard to find simple information on